# Asp.Net Core MVC Ajax tag helper - Return error from controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am building a Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC solution, using onion architecture.
I have just implemented the AJAX tag helpers for a partial view modal form POST.
[This is one of the arcticles I found and followed.](https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/) The "success" scenario works perfectly without any issues. My **main issue** comes in when my business service layer **throws an invalid operation exception**. This exception is caught by the MVC controller method and then added into a view model property named "ServiceError". My MVC controller method returns a partial view with the complete view model, which includes the error message. The DIV for the error message is not showing the error, upon return from the MVC controller method.
The **second issue** comes in here, the AJAX tag helpers is not detecting this as a failure. It still fires the "success" JS script. I have done several searches but cannot seem to find an example or docs on how to return errors from the MVC controller back to the modal using the AJAX tag helpers?

Here is my form tag code:

```
 <form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right" 
  id="formAddress" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Address" 
  asp-area="Admin" data-ajax="true"
  data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-complete="onComplete"
  data-ajax-success="onSuccess"
  data-ajax-failure="onFailed">
```

This is my MVC controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ViewModel.AddressViewModel addressViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newId = await _addressServiceClient.CreateAddress(addressViewModel);
                addressViewModel.Id = newId;
            }
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException ioex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(ViewModel.AddressViewModel), ioex.Message);
            addressViewModel.ServiceError = ioex.Message.ToString();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            addressViewModel.ServiceError = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        return PartialView("~/Areas/Shared/Views/_AddAddressPartial.cshtml", addressViewModel);
    }
```

Here is the div that displays the service error property:

```
@if (Model.ServiceError != "")
 {
    <div class="alert alert-danger">@Model.ServiceError</div>
 }
```

As per the comment from Stephen, I tried the below change and its not updating the ajax div I have setup.
[image: AJAX Update div]

Comment: You catch the error in the controller and then you return a valid result (your partial). Your `onFailed` function will only ever be triggered if there is a error response (e.g. if you did not catch the exception)

Comment: And you do not do anything with the partial you return (there is no target element specified to update)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried your suggestion, its still not updating the form or the new DIV after successfull AJAX post from my controller method.

Comment: Your updated code looks OK, however you should stop using the obsolete `ajax-*` (The `Ajax.BeginForm()` etc method were dropped for a reason) and use the jquery `$.ajax() methods which give you more flexibility anyway

Comment: I have used `ajax-*` successfully with the form tag helpers. Like what @StephenMuecke said, I have try catch in my code too to generate customer error messages (and log the exceptions on backend). Hence I only need to use `data-ajax-begin` and `data-ajax-complete`. Also instead of returning the view model back, I return json object using `Return Json()` and have a generic class to craft out the json response.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I went back to JQuery AJAX. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the feedback given by Stephen. I reverted my code to the JQuery AJAX method. I thought the data-ajax helpers were the new preferred way of doing AJAX in .NET core? Plus its less code! :-)

Here is the working code.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: createAddressUrl,
    data: $('#formAddress').serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
       //POST returned error
        if (!result.success) {
            var mvcError = "";
            mvcError = result.responseText;
            swal({
                "title": "1-Create address ERROR!",
                "text": mvcError,
                "type": "error",
                "confirmButtonClass": "btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--wide"
            });
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#m_modal').modal('hide').slideDown();
            window.location.reload();
        }   
    },
    error: function (result) {
        var mvcError = "";
        mvcError = result.responseText;
        swal({
            "title": "2-Create address submission FAILED!",
            "text": mvcError,
            "type": "error",
            "confirmButtonClass": "btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--wide"
        });
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: You are not alone - I used the very same article and it appears the tag helpers for ajax are not working with asp.net core 2.2